# wpf mvvm model inside model for parent child relationship and nested views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and it is not clear to me what to do when my business logic has a model inside another model for a parent child relationship and I want my Views and ViewModel to represent it.
Meaning I want the child View to be independent and reusable (I use UserControl) and has its own ViewModel and the parent View to have an element of the child and also its own ViewModel

The solution I can think of is to create a wrapper in parent ViewModel that create ViewModel of child from the parent model

Can you tell me if this is how it meant to be? or if there a better best practice to do that?

Here is a Pseudocode of what I mean where student is the parent and teacher is the child

// The child model
    class TeacherModel
    {
        public string teacherName { get; set; }
    }

```
// The parent model (the student has a teacher)
class StudentModel
{
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public TeacherModel teacherModel { get; set; }
}

class TeacherViewModel
{
    public TeacherModel teacherModel { get; set; }
}

class StudentViewModel
{
    public StudentModel studentModel { get; set; }

    // Is this good parctice?
    public TeacherViewModel wrapperTeacherViewModel
    {
        get
        {
           TeacherViewModel tempTeacherViewModel = new TeacherViewModel();
           tempTeacherViewModel.teacherModel = studentModel.teacherModel;
           return tempTeacherViewModel;
        }
    }
}

class TecherView : UserControl
{
    //TextBox binded to teacherModel.teacherName using Text="{Binding teacherModel.teacherName}"
}

class StudentView : UserControl
{
    // TextBox binded to studentModel.studentId using Text="{Binding studentModel.studentId}"

    // Is this good parctice?
    // TecherView binded to wrapperTeacherViewModel usinng DataContext="{Binding wrapperTeacherViewModel}"
}

class Porgram
{
    void main()
    {
        TeacherModel teacherModel = new TeacherModel();
        teacherModel.teacherName = "Marry";
        StudentModel studentModel = new StudentModel();
        studentModel.studentId = 12345;
        studentModel.teacherModel = teacherModel;

        StudentViewModel studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();
        studentViewModel.studentModel = studentModel;

        StudentView studentView = new StudentView();
        studentView.DataContext = studentView;
    }
}
```

I noticed an issues with solution. If i want my inner view model (Teacher) to have a property that does not exists in the model for example "enabled". That is because I never create TeacherViewModel instance myself so I do not have a chance to set something like teacherViewModel.enabled = false

Comment: You don't need to think of it as a wrapper though, it's just another view model.

Comment: But does the code looks ok?

Comment: `wrapperTeacherViewModel` should be `WrapperTeacherViewModel` as it's public other than that it looks fine.